# Do we require IOS device to Code Sign before App distribution

Tags: ios, code-signing

I have completed the IOS development and now needs to Deploy it in Store.
But as per the Developer website it says

> "Request Certificates with Xcode Xcode is the easiest way to request
>   certificates. Connect your device to your Mac and click Use for
>   Development in Xcode's Organizer window. Sign in with the Apple ID
>   associated with your iOS Developer Program membership and Xcode will
>   automatically generate your certificates."

I have done the development process with just an Appleid and Simulator not with an actual device or Certificates. But now got to know we need to create certificate as well as actual device connected to do the Code signing. Any other alternative for this because I don't have an Iphone.
Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Edit
Tried the option as the answer but now its showing as the below image:
[image]

Comment: technically you are able to complete your entire app on a simulator only _(highly __not__ recommended!)_ without having any certificate, then you could enroll the Developer Program for the distribution only; but the simulator does not support everything and you might not be able to test certain features on simulator – but for creating the archive of your app, you don't need to have any extra hardware.

Comment: thanks for the information @holex

Answer (score 0):

Right below that section, it says this:

> **Request Certificates Manually**
>
> To request certificates, upload a [Certificate Signing Request](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action) from
>   your Mac.

Comment: thanks alot.. let me check it. Actually I never knew what was it.

Comment: I had now down the steps according to the Certificate Signing Request, but now after that it asks for device to be connected. Please see the question edited. thanks